Не создается файл через функцию open() в python
Пытаюсь создать файл через функцию open() в python. В качестве аргумента режима функции open передается 'x'(создание файла в случае, если он не существует). Проблема в том, что при запуске программы файл как-бы создается, однако в проводнике он не отображается. Даже если я пытаюсь открыть этот файл через поле выполнить(Win+R), мне пишут что данного файла не существует. Запуская программу повторно(после создания файла) выдает ошибку, что данный файл существует. Т.е пайтон данный файл видит, а сама Windows 11 его не видит(Такая же история происходит с созданием папки). Я пытался записать данные в этот файл через пайтон, и на удивление у меня это получилось. Затем, я решил прочесть данные из этого файла, и прога мне вывела то, что я написал в этот файл через пайтон. Вот код:
def create_file(file_name, path=''):
    if path == '':
        try:
            open(file_name, 'x')
        except FileExistsError:
            print('This file has already exists!')
    else:
        try:
            open(path + '/' + file_name, 'x')
        except FileExistsError:
            print('This file has already exists!')


create_file("main1.txt", "C:/Users/hablu/Desktop/VSCProjects/OSmodule")
_file = open('main.py', 'a', encoding='utf-8')
_file.write('iwwxni')
_file = open('main1.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
print(_file.read())
_file.close()


Путь из агрумента create_file полностью совпадает с папкой, где лежит запускаемый скрипт? И если через F5 обновить?

Ещё у Вас работа ведется просто через open() и только в конце вызывается close(). По данному обсуждению ОС может не создавать файл, если его корректно не закрыть. Проще всего для этого использовать менеджер контекста with, который автоматически будет вызывать close() по окончании своей работы.

Файлы нужно закрывать. Либо должен быть close на каждый open, либо используйте конструкцию with open, тогда файл будет закрыт автоматически при выходе из блока with.
